# kubectl top nodes command gives only CPU and Memory usage, how to get GPU usage information in Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: linux, shell, kubernetes, gpu, kubectl

I'm using Kubernetes 1.7 and I have a GPU machine in the cluster. The `kubectl top nodes` gives only CPU and Memory usage like this

```
NAME       CPU(cores)   CPU%      MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
machine1   183m         1%        5284Mi          8%
machine2   181m         1%        5543Mi          8%
machine3   250m         1%        7682Mi          7%
machine4   328m         5%        1578Mi          16%
```

Is there a way to get **GPU usage**?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that `kubectl top` does not provide GPU metrics, regardless if drivers are installed or not.

To inspect GPU statistics, I recommend using [Heapster](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/storage-schema.md) monitoring tool
and [Prometheus](https://github.com/chhibber/pgme) that provides the extension to get the accelerator metrics.

At last, you may be interested in [Nvidia GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/kubernetes-gpu) works for Kubernetes and [GCE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/gpus) concepts of using this kind of hardware.

Comment: I used Heapster and  Prometheus before but I think Heapster is deprecated. I'm using nvidia-smi for now but let's see if i find a better solution. Thanks

Comment: I mentioned [pgme tool](https://github.com/chhibber/pgme) regarding to the Prometheus link. Please leave a note if it helps a bit.